# USB drive not recognized

Tags: usb, usb-drive, fdisk, dmesg

I am trying to access important files on a HAMA Classic USB 3.0 Flash Drive, to no avail. It worked fine yesterday but now it doesn't seem to be properly recognized.

The drive is there in lsusb (this line is only visible when the drive is plugged in):

```
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 058f:6387 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
```

However it isn't recognized by sudo fdisk -l, there only being:

```
Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          2048 1241874431 1241872384 592.2G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1241876478 1250263039    8386562     4G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1241876480 1250263039    8386560     4G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

output of lsblk:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0 140.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/98
loop1    7:1    0  24.7M  1 loop /snap/snapd/6434
loop2    7:2    0   3.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/135
loop3    7:3    0   4.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/704
loop4    7:4    0   956K  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/93
loop5    7:5    0  93.8M  1 loop /snap/core/8935
loop6    7:6    0 160.2M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116
loop7    7:7    0  14.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/495
loop8    7:8    0  91.4M  1 loop /snap/core/8689
loop9    7:9    0  48.3M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1474
loop10   7:10   0    55M  1 loop /snap/core18/1705
loop11   7:11   0    27M  1 loop /snap/snapd/6953
loop12   7:12   0  54.8M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1502
loop13   7:13   0  83.9M  1 loop /snap/drawio/20
loop14   7:14   0  84.2M  1 loop /snap/drawio/21
sda      8:0    0 596.2G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 592.2G  0 part /
└─sda5   8:5    0     4G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

These are the lines i'm getting with dmesg:

```
[ 1311.475152] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[ 1312.245074] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=6387
[ 1312.245083] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1312.245087] usb 2-2: Product: Hama                
[ 1312.245091] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Alcor          
[ 1312.245094] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 44EE41FB
[ 1312.246145] usb-storage 2-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1312.250183] scsi host7: usb-storage 2-2:1.0
[ 1334.144130] usb 2-2: reset high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
```

I've also tried the USB drive in a windows computer, and i get a similar issue - theres a sound to suggest it is recognized but i can't access the files. If anyone can give me any idea on how to recover the files it would be greatly appreciated.

sudo fdisk -l:

```
sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 140.7 MiB, 147501056 bytes, 288088 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 24.7 MiB, 25915392 bytes, 50616 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 3.7 MiB, 3862528 bytes, 7544 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 4.3 MiB, 4464640 bytes, 8720 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 956 KiB, 978944 bytes, 1912 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 93.8 MiB, 98336768 bytes, 192064 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 160.2 MiB, 167931904 bytes, 327992 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 14.8 MiB, 15466496 bytes, 30208 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes




Disk /dev/sda: 596.2 GiB, 640135028736 bytes, 1250263728 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x6ce5e98e

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          2048 1241874431 1241872384 592.2G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1241876478 1250263039    8386562     4G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1241876480 1250263039    8386560     4G 82 Linux swap / Solaris


Disk /dev/loop8: 91.4 MiB, 95805440 bytes, 187120 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop9: 48.3 MiB, 50642944 bytes, 98912 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop10: 55 MiB, 57614336 bytes, 112528 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop11: 27 MiB, 28356608 bytes, 55384 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop12: 54.8 MiB, 57479168 bytes, 112264 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop13: 83.9 MiB, 87916544 bytes, 171712 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop14: 84.2 MiB, 88244224 bytes, 172352 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

ls -Alh /dev/sda*:

```
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 Apr 18 21:26 /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 1 Apr 18 21:26 /dev/sda1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 2 Apr 18 21:26 /dev/sda2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 5 Apr 18 21:26 /dev/sda5
```

Comment: What does `ls -Alh /dev/sdb*` show?

Comment: It shows the same thing both when its plugged in and when it isnt: `brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 16 Apr 18 21:26 /dev/sdb`. Also if it matters, I actually last used it the day before yesterday, so I assume that's what the time stamp refers to.

Comment: Try `sudo fdisk -l` as `/dev/sdb` can only be read by root. And what does `ls -Alh /dev/sda*` show?

Comment: I have added them both in the question section

Comment: Hmm, does `reset high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci` message appear once or many times?

Comment: Just once. I leave it for a few minutes and get the same output as in the question.